# Solve for the limit determining value "a"

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine the value of a so that the

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxywC.png)
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=3
$$
I have tried doing L'Hopital but I can't make it goes into a division of infinite.
Also I thought of "a" being 3 so that if I manage to cancel the 1/x making it 0 and then the (a^1/x) would be a=3 but i figured i could do it.
Then i tried aplying the binary theorem to make an infinite sums but that would just diverge to infinity.

the limit that I tried to expand into was
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x+\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=3
$$
but I figured it cant be done like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot I tried to clarify the problem, is it ok now?

Comment: @Chema Take a tour: [math.stackexchange.com/tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: [math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: @Chema: You should also show your own efforts to get your question answered.

Comment: @Zaragosa do i add what i have tried so far in the problem or here in the comments?

Comment: @Chema add your intent in the same question

Comment: @Zaragosa ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $a^{1/x}$ is well defined for $a>0$. Let $f(x)=a^{1/x}+\frac{1}{x}-1$, let us also note that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1+f(x)\right)^x=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left[(1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}\right]^{x\cdot f(x)}=e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)}
$$
We then focus our attention on
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}1+x(a^{1/x}-1)\\[2mm]
&=1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a^{1/x}-1}{1/x}\\[2mm]
&=1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{-a^{1/x}\ln a}{x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\[2mm]
&=1+\lim_{x\to\infty}a^{1/x}\ln a\\[1mm]
&=1+\ln a
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
3=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)}=e^{1+\ln a}
$$
then we have $a=3/e$.

Comment: in the part where you make e^x to the limit how do you cancel the part inside the limit, just leaving the x*f(x)?

Comment: i did the function in a graph and yes it is that answer but i also tried doing this, $$ (a^x/x +.....1/x^x)$$, and all the inside dots will cancel bc they are divided by x going to inf, so i thought that a+1/x^x=3 and by doing the limits it would be just a=3

Comment: @Chema remember that the same $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$...

Comment: @Chema I don't know where this comes from:$(a^x/x +.....1/x^x)$. Remember that using Newton's binomial is ruled out since $x\not\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: oh, i thought that i could use the binomial theorem to expand it first and then si what can be canceled

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y=\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\implies \log(y)=x \log\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Let $t=\frac 1 x$
$$\log\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\log\left(a^{t}+t\right)$$ By Taylor
$$\log\left(a^{t}+t\right)= (\log (a)+1)t- \left(\log (a)+\frac{1}{2}\right)t^2+O\left(t^3\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\frac 1 t\Bigg[(\log (a)+1)t- \left(\log (a)+\frac{1}{2}\right)t^2+O\left(t^3\right) \Bigg]$$
$$\log(y)=(\log (a)+1)- \left(\log (a)+\frac{1}{2}\right)t+O\left(t^2\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e a-e a  \left(\log (a)+\frac{1}{2}\right)t+O\left(t^2\right)=e a+O\left(t^1\right)$$ So $e a=3$ and $a=\frac 3 e$